# Nginx Rewrite causing problems

Tags: nginx

I wrote a little php script that reads and compresses css and javascript files. I used a rewrite to automatically redirect all resources to that script. The rule looks like this:

```
rewrite ^(/.*\.(css|js))$ /compress.php?file=$1&type=$2;
```

However this somehow disables these settings:

```
location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
  expires 168h;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

How do I get Nginx to still use these settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a separate block for the `css` / `js` files, and include the `rewrite` directive inside that directive, like this:

```
location ~* (?<filename>.+\.(?<type>css|js))$ {
    expires 168h;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    rewrite ^ /compress.php?file=$filename&type=$type;
}
```

Here I use regex captures on the `location` directive, and capture to named variables. It is just a matter of taste how you do the captures though.

And then reduce the other block to:

```
location ~* \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
```

I use `?:` prefix here to indicate that we don't need to make any regex captures.

If that doesn't work, then you have to set the cache headers inside your `compress.php` script with `header()` function.

Comment: Ok. It is still not working. I guess I have to stick defining the headers in php...